Giant Crest fork NEGATIVE pressure
my child runs a Giant Crest 34 RCL, that is newish (couple months old,) and has been fine for the past few weeks that they have ridden. They run about 60PSI, and testing the rebound makes no difference.
However, recently, they have complained that it feels “too plush,” so I took a look and have found that the stanchion actually sucks itself Down into the tube a fair amount (5-10mm.) I have tried re adjusting and re-pressurising the negative air chamber, and the whole fork in general.
I have done research and found nothing.
Before my last resort of getting it properly serviced, is there anything I can try?

Have you tried putting the tip of a cable tie down between dust wiper seals and stanchions? You might have some pressure in your lowers, which you can release this way. Dust wipers and stanchions have to be very clean if you try this.

Has the bike been exposed to high temperatures?  left in a hot place ?

Criggie, the bike has not, but I’ll take not of that one- thanks very much for your suggestion reciprocal lettuce!

What you're describing is a condition called fork "suck down" and is caused by too much air pressure in the negative air spring. Excess pressure in an air negative spring causes the stanchions to move into their travel.  The fork will feel mushy and wallow during low speed compression acts like body movement, cornering or braking.
Modern air springs utilize air pressure in both the positive side and negative. Earlier air springs used a couple of coil springs for the negative spring, which is designed to give the positive spring something to push against during compression.  Inside the stanchion of a dual air fork is a dimple called a transfer port. This allows air to flow between the positive side and negative side. When the air piston passes over the transfer port, air is exchanged between positive and negative chambers.
If the transfer port becomes clogged with grease or debris, air doesn't transfer between positive and negative sides causing excess pressure to remain in the negative side.  Another cause of air pressure buildup is a scratch or flaw in the air seals which can cause build up of air in the negative spring.
The best option is to perform a lowers service on the fork and inspect the seals and note any grease or debris in the transfer port.  It's common for the factory to apply excess grease to the air piston and this grease finds it's way into the transfer port, blocking proper air exchange.  You can try to inflate the positive chamber to max pressure and cycle the fork repeatedly as a means to clear a port blockage. Release all pressure from both positive and negative chambers and reinflate to recommended settings and then adjust so the fork achieves desired sag level.
Here is a video discussing fork suck down and maintenance to solve it.

Thank you very much- I was online when your answer popped up! I will try it out!
